# Article partitif : combien de formes ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, partitif

Je me demande pourquoi il n'y a pas de consensus entre les livres de grammaire du français à propos de l'article partitif et ses formes. Par exemple :

- Le livre A French Reference Grammar (1967, H. Ferrar), mentionne que l'article partitif ne possède que deux formes (du-masculin ; de la/de l'-féminin ou mots masculins qui commencent par voyelle ou h-muet).
  Il montre l'emploi de l'article en employant des propositions comme :

> On me donne du fromage, du sel et de la moutarde. De la glace couvrait
> les fossés.

- Un autre livre que je consulte fréquemment - Student Grammar of French (2006, M. Offord) - affirme qu'il y a **trois** formes de l'article partitif. À savoir: celles du singulier susmentionnés et la forme *des* pour le pluriel.
  Il donne des exemples tels que:

> On boit **des** verres, on fait du jogging...

> Comment peut-on faire un dessert aussi délicieux et aussi pratique
> avec juste du lait, **des** œufs frais, du sucre, du caramel et un peu de
> vanille ?

C-à-d que ce livre-ci distingue entre le des qui se réfère à un nombre indéterminé d'objets dénombrables (article indéfini) et le des qui se réfère  aux objets ou gens envisagés dans le cadre d'un ensemble (article partitif).

En revanche, ce livre-là traite du cas **des** comme le pluriel de l'article indéfini.

Alors, quel livre est correct ici ? S'agit-il seulement d'une approche linguistique différente ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le nom introduit par un article partitif est généralement au singulier puisqu'il représente un ensemble non dénombrable, comme dans ***de** l'eau*.

« ***Des** eaux* » ne peut pas être un partitif mais représente un ensemble d'eaux distinctes.

L'article partitif doit cependant être au pluriel si le nom au pluriel qui suit est quand même indénombrable car il ne représente pas un ensemble d'entités disjointes :

> Il passe ***des*** vacances formidables à la mer.
>
> Il passe <s>deux vacances</s> formidables...
>
> Ils caractérisent merveilleusement l'orgueil du Prince ***des*** Ténèbres.
>
> ...du Prince des <s>quatre</s> Ténèbres.

La frontière est parfois floue entre l'article indéfini et l'article partitif:

> Hier, j'ai mangé ***des*** frites avec ***de*** la mayonnaise.

***Des*** peut être ici considéré comme l'un ou l'autre car il est difficile d'écrire :

> Hier, j'ai mangé **de la** frite avec **de la** mayonnaise.

Comment: Merci ! C-à-d que le livre le plus récent est correct ici car il distingue entre des-partitif et des-indéfini, n'est-ce pas ? Par contre, le livre ancien est incorrect en affirmant que la forme des ne correspond qu'au pluriel de l'article indéfini. Y êtes-vous d'accord ?

Comment: Oui, le premier livre ne tient pas compte des mots qui n'ont pas de singulier et dont l'article partitif doit nécessairement être au pluriel (sauf en cas de négation).